# Network traffic monitoring per android application

Tags: android, android-networking

I was wondering if I can do network traffic monitoring per android application?

Basically see which app is receiving/sending how much data?

I know there are many apps which already do that but I want to know how to do it.

Answer (score 3):

Well you surely can. A very simple way is to use the [TrafficStats](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/TrafficStats.html) class. It can manage per app (more formally, per UID) But the problem is, it can return `UNSUPPORTED`. When this happens, I don't think you will have some easy (i.e. using the high level Java language) method to get the network traffic data you need.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if it can be implemented in Java as I imagine you need to access some low-level Operating system functions which are just not available in Java (but don't quote me on this!).

The obvious way I see of doing this is through C language and the Android Native Development Kit.