# How to programatically show data usage of all applications?

Tags: android, android-service, usage-statistics, android-data-usage

I am trying to find out the data usage in Android on a per-application basis. Something like
 http://kschang.hubpages.com/hub/Data-Usage-Monitor-Apps-and-Widgets-for-Android-Phones-and-Devices#slide4646427

I've searched many links and posts on Stackoverflow, but none of them helped me.

I've tried to search API for usage data in Android but didn't find any thing to solve my problem.

Now the question is how to know, how much data used by each application.
Actually I need a solution which gives data usage of applications in a given time period i.e. in each month.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35908483/how-to-get-data-usage-for-last-1-month-in-android/35910250#35910250). You can filter by different apps and different time spans easily.

Comment: That is not what I wanted. I mean I want how to programatically an app for show data usage of each application or total data usage of all application @Milan Vucic

Comment: Oops, looks like I misunderstood then. Is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18758331/5647037) what you're looking for?

Comment: I want to program an android app, which will show data usage of each application in my mobile